# SPView.Clone Method

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I'm showing a view within a webpart and I update this view to filter the list items according to the logged on user's groups. Is there a way to clone the view and update it leaving intact the original one? I need this cloned view to be temporarary since I don't need it after rendering it.
I know there's a SPView.Clone method but it's little documented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the clone-d view will be persisted to the database. You can take a look at [ListViewByQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.aspx) class.

EDIT: An example + explanation can be found here: http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/the-listviewbyquery-control/ (this even shows how to use grouping in such views)

Comment: Thanks naivists. ListViewByQuery class was what I was looking for!